# Regex Regular Expression for Number Range Check between -2 and 5

Tags: regex

I've got the following regular expression shown below which checks the range between 0 and 5.

^(([0-4])+(.\d)?)|((5)+(.0)?)$

I will need to change it so it checks the range between -2 to 5 instead but am not familiar with this code.

Can I get someone to make a quick change so the expression will then check between -2 and 5 please.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your regular expression you gave allows for numbers with multiple digits before the decimal point such as `100` or `41.0`. It also allows for multiple matches on the same line such as `2.05.0`.

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Thanks for the feedback. If that is the case then I will someone to re-write the whole thing :(

Comment: It appears you wish to be able to match `2` or `2.3` but not `2.34`. Correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland 
I would like to match to 2 decimal places (e.g 2.34)

Comment: Then `2` or `2.34` but not `2.3`? Please edit your question to make that clear. (Readers should not be expected to read the comments to understand the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for all numbers from -2.0 to 5.0 inclusive which have 0 or 1 digit after the decimal place:

`^((-[0-1]|[0-4])(\.\d)?|(-2|5)(\.0)?)$`

Test cases: https://regex101.com/r/bInayE/2/

If you want to allow any number of digits after the decimal place (ex. 2.157):

`^((-[0-1]|[0-4])(\.\d+)?|(-2|5)(\.0+)?)$`

Test cases: https://regex101.com/r/zp01M6/3/

#### In case you want to be able to update these in the future:

- `[0-1]` refers to the range of digits which can be preceded by a minus sign and have digits after a decimal point
- `[0-4]` is the range of digits which can have digits after a decimal point without being preceded by a minus sign
- `(-2|5)` are the numbers which can only be followed by .0

#### Update:

- Shortened both expressions by combining the -2 and 5 cases as suggested by  @Robert McKee.
- Added case for negative numbers starting with 0 as pointed out by @Cary Swoveland

Comment: Just tested this one also. It does not match 0.1 to 0.9.

Comment: @Rhys 0.1 to 0.9 should be fine since it allows any number 0-4 followed by a decimal and a digit. The case of -0.9 to -0.1 was mistakenly left out, but it has now been added in. I will also add in an explanation of the regex so it makes more sense what it does.

Comment: Should -0 be valid?  Should .5 be valid? Should -.5 be valid?

Comment: @Robert, you should direct your question to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that we are to match integers and floats with one decimal digit that fall between -2 and 5.

You can use the following regular expression with virtually all languages.

```
r = /\A(?:-2(?:\.0)?|-1(?:\.\d)?|-0\.[1-9]|[0-4](?:\.\d)?|5(?:\.0)?)\z/
```

Here I test it with Ruby.

```
'-2'.match? r    #=> true
'-2.0'.match? r  #=> true
'-1.8'.match? r  #=> true
'-1.0'.match? r  #=> true
'-1'.match? r    #=> true
'-0.3'.match? r  #=> true
'0'.match? r     #=> true
'0.0'.match? r   #=> true
'0.3'.match? r   #=> true
'3'.match? r     #=> true
'3.3'.match? r   #=> true
'5'.match? r     #=> true
'5.0'.match? r   #=> true

'-2.1'.match? r  #=> false
'-1.85'.match? r #=> false
'-0'.match? r    #=> false
'-0.0'.match? r  #=> false
'0.34'.match? r  #=> false
'5.1'.match? r   #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex are an awkward way to check for ranges, so I would suggest you try validating ranges in a more traditional way. I remember doing something similar
to validate ip addresses, and it got a lot more complicated than I expected.

With that said, that regex you pasted doesn't actually check for a 0-5 range. In fact, you could get any char in there, after a "5" and before a "0" (something like `5f0` for instance).

With a regex like the one below, you could validate the input in this set `{-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}`. You may add the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, so the regex matches the whole line.

```
(-[1-2]|[0-5])
```

Comment: I was just able to test this and it worked great!!!
This was much simpler then what I was trying to do.
Thank you very much @pable

Comment: @Rhys So you want 1.5 to be invalid?

Comment: @RobertMcKee - Your correct. I was only testing whole number but decimal places need to work also.